# Hyperref package makes not appear year in citations using apacite style

Tags: kile

I am creating a kind draft of references pdf, when I use apacite package anly, it works, when I add hyperref package years in citations do not appear.

[image: Those kind of problems appear on other hand, they do not appear when I am not using hyperref package]

[image: The ouput]

Comment: Wellcome to SE! Please provide Minimal Working Example (MWE) which will show your problem.